# Adding new private entry key using pydicom

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydicom

I need to add the corresponding text keys of tags to pydicom so it can read them from a DICOM file. So far I have been able to add the entries to the DICOM file using the `add_new()` method. However, I still have to read these values using the hexa codes.

I have checked the [documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/api_ref.html#pydicom.datadict.add_private_dict_entry), and there is a method called `add_private_dict_entries` for this. However, I cannot seem to find this method in pydicom. I have followed exactly as in the example:

```
from pydicom import Dataset
toing_dicom_attr = {
                0x270f03e9: ('SH', 1, 'Was Viewed By TOINGTOING'),
                0x270f03ea: ('SH', 1, 'At Least One toing toing'),
            }
add_private_dict_entries("TOINGSCOMPANY", toing_dicom_attr)
```

However I get the following Error:

> NameError: name 'add_private_dict_entries' is not defined

I have also tried using `pydicom.datadict.add_private_dict_entries()` but it does not work. How can I get my private attributes to be readable by my pydicom installation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The documentation you linked is in the "dev" branch, i.e. not in a released version, only in the repository.  Which version of pydicom are you using?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I was indeed using the dev documentation. This is the correct link: https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/api_ref.html#module-pydicom.datadict . This method is not available in stable yet. It makes sense now. I use the latest stable version

Answer (score 1):

There is an example that does what you want.

https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/auto_examples/metadata_processing/plot_add_dict_entries.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-metadata-processing-plot-add-dict-entries-py

Answer (score 1):

You did not import add_private_dict_entries correctly:

```
from pydicom import Dataset
from pydicom.datadict import add_private_dict_entries


toing_dicom_attr = {
                0x270f03e9: ('SH', 1, 'Was Viewed By TOINGTOING'),
                0x270f03ea: ('SH', 1, 'At Least One toing toing'),
            }
add_private_dict_entries("TOINGSCOMPANY", toing_dicom_attr)
```

would work.